# unable to connect to hive with dbt and kerberos

Tags: hive, kerberos, dbt

My goal is to make data quality checks against the data which is stored in hive on a cluster.
I'm using dbt-core, dbt-hive libraries, and I have troubles connecting to that data.
My profiles.yml looks like this:

```
project:
  outputs:
    dev:
      host: test.com
      port: 10000
      schema: default
      type: hive
      auth_type: KERBEROS
      kerberos_service_name: hive
      use_http_transport: true
      use_ssl: true
  target: dev
```

With this config the error I'm getting when doing "dbt debug" is

```
dbt was unable to connect to the specified database.
The database returned the following error:

>Runtime Error
Unable to establish connection to Hive server: Failed after retrying 3 times
```

When I connect using pyhive module, I have a full access:

```
conn_hive = hive.Connection(host="test.com", port=10000, scheme="default", auth="KERBEROS", kerberos_service_name="hive")
```

I'm not sure if the runtime error posted above is a step forward or a step back. I've tried to play with false/true and other things. Also I don't know who and how configured the cluster, and I'm just a user.

Can anyone help me how to fix this issue?